# add class with scrolling bottom of page

Tags: jquery, class, navigation, scroll

I have right/bottom fixed navigation like this.

```
<div style='position:fixed; bottom:10px; right:10px;'>NAVIGATION</div>
```

when scrolling to the bottom of page, I want to add class (bottom:100px) to navigation.
some help :-)

Answer (score 4):

you could do,

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   $("#yourNavigationId").removeClass("some_class");
   if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() == $(document).height()) {
       //you are at bottom
       $("#yourNavigationId").addClass("some_class");
   }
});
```

Comment: Thank you, Sudhir. how to remove class when scrolling to top again?

Answer (score 0):

If you need some more functionalities, there's an awesome plugin called jQuery [Waypoints](http://imakewebthings.com/jquery-waypoints/).

You may want to check it out.